# Llenar combobox en C# con consultas separadas con (,)

Tags: mysql, c#, combobox

tengo una duda que no he podido aun solucionar
tengo un combobox que se llena desde BD el problema reside en que algunos datos vienen agrupados y separados por comas(,) y no se como hacer para llenar el cmb con cada dato ya separado, por ahora lo tengo en un for pero eso solo me trae el primer dato, me podrian echar una mano por favor?
gracias

```
char delimitador = ',';

string Queryid2 = "SELECT fk_id_bines,fk_id_ubicacion FROM producto_bines_rel WHERE 
fk_id_producto=@codig_prod AND activo=1 ;"; //realizo la consulta
                MySqlCommand cmid2 = new MySqlCommand(Queryid2, con.ObtenerConexion());
                cmid2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codig_prod", id);

                MySqlDataReader readerid2 = cmid2.ExecuteReader();

                if (readerid2.Read())
                {
                    string bines = readerid2["fk_id_bines"].ToString();

                    string[] valores = bines.Split(delimitador);
                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++)
                    {

                       Cmb_Bin.Text = (valores[i].ToString());
                        
                    }
                   
                    Cmb_ubicacion.Text = readerid2["fk_id_ubicacion"].ToString();
                }

                readerid2.Close();
```

Comment: creo que tu problema mas bien es que solo lees el primer registro que te regresa el reader,  ve el ejemplo de aquí [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), aplican un `while (reader.Read())`

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

```
string Queryid2 = "SELECt b.nombre_bines as bines,u.nombre_ubicacion as ubicaciones  FROM producto_bines_rel p,bines b,ubicaciones u WHERE p.fk_id_producto=@codig_prod and p.activo=1 and p.fk_id_ubicacion = u.id_ubicacion and p.fk_id_bines = b.id_bines and p.fk_id_malmacen= @codig_almacen; "; 
                MySqlCommand cmid2 = new MySqlCommand(Queryid2, con.ObtenerConexion());
                cmid2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codig_prod", id);
                cmid2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codig_almacen", cod_almacen);

                MySqlDataReader readerid2 = cmid2.ExecuteReader();

                if (readerid2.Read())
                {
                    string bines = readerid2["bines"].ToString();

                    string[] valores = bines.Split(delimitador);
               
                    Cmb_Bin.Items.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++)
                    {

                        Cmb_Bin.Items.Add(valores[i]);
                                               
                    }                   
                    Cmb_ubicacion.Text = readerid2["ubicaciones"].ToString();
                    
                }
                readerid2.Close();
```